# Consulta mysql con comodin

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hola amigos tengo una duda existencial respecto de como hacer una consulta  a la bd con un valor que se a un comodin y que este se vaya en una variable, esta algo enredado, pero les muestro mi codigo a ver si me entienden mejor:

Yo hago una consulta  la bd con tres variables que estan contenidas en listas desplegables asi:

```
<select id="cl_act" name="abo" class="form-control" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" >
        <?php $filter1 = (isset($_GET['abo']) ? strtolower($_GET['abo']) : NULL);  ?>
        <option value="PEPITO PEREZ 1" <?php if ($filter1 =="PEPITO PEREZ 1"){echo "selected";} ?>>PEPITO PEREZ 1</option>
<option value="PEPITO PEREZ 2" <?php if ($filter1 =="PEPITO PEREZ 2"){echo "selected";} ?>>PEPITO PEREZ 2</option>
<option value="PEPITO PEREZ 3" <?php if ($filter1 =="PEPITO PEREZ 3"){echo "selected";} ?>>PEPITO PEREZ 3</option>
<option value="???" <?php if ($filter1 =="???"){echo "selected";} ?>>TODOS LOS PEPITOS PEREZ</option>
    </select>
```

Posteriormente, recojo el valor de la variable a traves del GET, lo paso a una variable y esa es la que me va a llevar en la consulta así:

```
if($filter1){
$sql = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM metas WHERE m_abo = '$filter1' ");
                }
```

Si en las opciones del select llevo a cualquiera de los tres pepitos, puedo hacer la consulta sin ningun porblema, ahora mi pregunta es, en el ultimo campo de mi input select quiero dar una opcion que se llame todos, refiriéndome a los 3 pepitos, es decir quiero que la consulta se haga sobre los tres pepitos, pero la verdad no se que debo poner en el value del input, para que sea una especie de comodin que me busque información sobre mi tres pepitos, se entiende?

Hay alguna forma en la que la que se pueda llevar un comodin para que en mi consulta ... WHERE m_abo ='$filter1'; entienda que busco informacion sobre todos los pepitos o usuarios de esta tabla?

quedo atento gracias

Comment: Si `$filter1` es igual a `???` **no agregues** a la consulta `WHERE m_abo = '$filter1'`

Comment: Hola, el valor ??? lo deje así en el código porque no se que debo poner ahí para que lo tome como comodín, me explico?

Comment: Lo que estás buscando es algo basado en `LIKE`, por ejemplo: `... WHERE m_abo LIKE '%pepito1%'  OR m_abo LIKE '%pepito2%' OR LIKE m_abo '%pepito3%'` ... Ese sería un ejemplo de consulta final para tu caso. [Revisa la doc sobre `LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html) porque hay varios marcadores según el tipo de filtro que quieras aplicar. Y, si son muchos LIKE se podría pensar en algo más potente como expresiones regulares. Por último, te aconsejaría el uso de consultas preparadas para evitar ataques de *Inyección SQL*.